# new Date() returning invalid date unless * by 1?

Tags: javascript, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have a JSON object returning a unix timestamp of content piece's publish dates. This timestamp returns as an invalid date when using `.toISOString()` unless I multiply it by 1.

As an example

```
let timestamp = item[index].date; // returns string of "1584632700000"
let invalidDate = new Date(timestamp).toISOString(); // returns invalid Date
let validDate = new Date(timestamp * 1).toISOString(); // returns valid (and correct) Date
```

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: `new Date( string )` will try to parse the string, while `new Date( number )` will take unix timespan, `timestamp * 1` will convert the string to a number so that works as you expect

Comment: You need to convert the string to a number for the timestamp `new Date(+timestamp)`

Comment: Please, consider reading the [MDN Date documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Especially the parameters section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason behind this is how **[`new Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)** interprets its arguments.

Looking at the relevant prototypes we see:

> new Date(value)
>
> new Date(dateString)

Where `value` is a number and `dateString` a string.

This means the function acts different when passed a string and a number.

`value` is described by MDN as:

> Integer value representing the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC, with leap seconds ignored (Unix Epoch; but consider that most Unix timestamp functions count in seconds).

And `dateString` as:

> String value representing a date. The string should be in a format recognized by the Date.parse() method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps and also a version of ISO8601).

Since you pass it a string, it will use the **second** approach which is trying to parse the date.

Now, why does it work with `* 1`?

`* 1` is converting the string to a number in an implicit manner.

You can also use **[`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)** to do this which is a bit more verbose:

```
new Date(parseInt('1584632700000', 10))
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me looking in the right direction, parseInit() will also return `NaN` instead of `0` if it's an empty string. Greatly appreciated!